# Java socket bind twice without exception

Tags: java, sockets, networking

When my Application, it bind on a given port when it started:

```
public boolean checkIsAlreadyStart() {
    try {
        final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
        server.setReuseAddress(false);
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",APPLICATION_PORT ));
        if (server.isBound()){
            logger.debug("binding to port: {}", APPLICATION_PORT);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("cannot bind to port", e);
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, when i run two instance of the Application at the same time, the second instance can still run the method without the IOException. Do I have to call accept() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce:

```
10/04/2013 3:55:34 PM S checkIsAlreadyStart
INFO: Bound to port: 9,999
10/04/2013 3:55:34 PM S checkIsAlreadyStart
SEVERE: cannot bind to port
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:286)
    at S.checkIsAlreadyStart(S.java:33)
    at S.main(S.java:63)
```

However as `server` is a local variable it is likely to allow garbage-collection of the `ServerSocket,` which will close it. If your intention is to keep the port open you should make `server` an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the first instance of the application is still running?  You could place a Thread.sleep in the application to be sure it is still running when you launch the second instance.

I ran this twice and the second time failed, as you intended.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Menu m = new Menu();
    m.checkIsAlreadyStart();
    try {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```